# Perl - IMAP search unicode string with X-GM-RAW

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, gmail, imap

I'm using **Perl** and **Mail::IMAPClient** module to search emails and fetch them from Gmail server, but stuck on problem with unicode strings in X-GM-RAW.

When I send command:

> SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW "Новости"

it doesn't work :(

But

> SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW "News"

works with no problems and returns list of message ids

My perl-script looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8::all;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mail::IMAPClient;

my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
    User     => 'username@gmail.com',
    Password => 'secr3t',
    Ssl      => 1,
    Uid      => 0,
    Debug    => 1
);

$imap->select('[Gmail]/All Mail');
my $news = $imap->search('CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW "Новости"');
print "@$news"; # print message ids
```

Debug messages:

```
Started at Wed Apr 15 00:25:43 2015
Using Mail::IMAPClient version 3.35 on perl 5.020002
Connecting with IO::Socket::SSL PeerAddr imap.gmail.com PeerPort 993 Proto tcp Timeout 600 Debug 1
Connected to imap.gmail.com
Read:   * OK Gimap ready for requests from 178.47.31.152 e1mb42229459lab
Sending: 1 LOGIN username@gmail.com secr3t
Sent 43 bytes
Read:   * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
    1 OK username@gmail.com authenticated (Success)
Sending: 2 SELECT "[Gmail]/All Mail"
Sent 29 bytes
Read:   * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $label3 $Phishing $Forwarded $MDNSent Old $NotJunk NotJunk NonJunk $NotPhishing Junk)
    * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $label3 $Phishing $Forwarded $MDNSent Old $NotJunk NotJunk NonJunk $NotPhishing Junk \*)] Flags permitted.
    * OK [UIDVALIDITY 596378645] UIDs valid.
    * 36992 EXISTS
    * 0 RECENT
    * OK [UIDNEXT 99973] Predicted next UID.
    * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 3390697]
    2 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/All Mail selected. (Success)
Sending: 3 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW "Новости"
Sent 41 bytes
...
```

and doesn't stop...
until I kill him with Ctrl+C

If you have already solved this problem, plz help!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send

```
0 ENABLE UTF8=ACCEPT
```

first. The `enable` command enables specific server features, in this case the relevant feature is the ability to use UTF-8 in a quoted string ("Новости"). RFCs 5161 and 6855 apply if you care to read more, but it's not really necessary.

All IMAP servers allow you to use UTF8 in a literal ({14}CRLFНовости) or nonsynchronising literal ({14+}CRLFНовости), but a quoted string is so much more convenient and gmail does support `enable`.

Answer (score 0):

Found method **Quote**, it does what you said:

> returns its argument as a correctly quoted string or a literal string.

and added block with **no utf8** pragma to switch back to treating the source text as literal bytes in the current lexical scope.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mail::IMAPClient;

my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => 'imap.gmail.com',
    User     => 'username@gmail.com',
    Password => 'secr3t',
    Ssl      => 1,
    Uid      => 0,
    Debug    => 1
);

$imap->select('[Gmail]/All Mail');

my $newsid_ref;
{
    no utf8;
    my $string = $imap->Quote("Новости");
    $newsid_ref = $imap->search('CHARSET UTF-8 X-GM-RAW ' . $string);
}
say for @$newsid_ref;
```

and now script works fine.